# Uso de DATE en PHP para mostrar la fecha y la hora

Tags: php, date

un saludo cordial.

Estoy usando en PHP la siguiente línea de código

```
date("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

Para mostrar la fecha en PHP, me funciona bien, me aparece la fecha, pero la hora la muestra 5 horas adelantada, que parámetro debo cambiar para que me ajuste bien?? creo que es algo de la zona horaria, pero no se que función cumplen la g: i a...

Gracias.

JUAN C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Establece la zona horaria acordé a la región en la que te encuentras de este modo:

```
date_default_timezone_set('aqui_la_zona_horaria');
```

Esta línea de código va antes de la función `date` que ya posees.

Para saber cómo colocar tu región geográfica extraerla de la lista oficial de PHP<sup>1</sup>, donde ingresas a tu país y después copias el valor de la columna de en medio y eso va como argumento de la función ya mencionada

**EJEMPLO 1**

Si yo estoy en México y pinto la hora así:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

echo date("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

Me da como resultado:

> 18:10:00

**EJEMPLO 2**

Pero si por el contrario solo la pinto así:

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

Obtengo algo así:

> 16:10:00

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)

Comment: Excelente, ya con la función date_default_timezone_set quedó ok. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Usa este código:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");
echo date('h:i:s A');
?>
```

Te dejo las zonas horarias:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.europe.php

Espero que te sirva